# Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop deployment

Tags: installation

I am looking for a way to deploy about 80-100 Ubuntu desktops at a school, when Ubuntu 12.04 is available. What would you prefer for deployment system, Microsoft Configuration manager cant do the task :)

Answer (score 1):

Canonical's Ubuntu Advantage program has a software called Landscape. You'll find it at http://landscape.canonical.com or in System Settings in a running 12.04 install.

Comment: I know landscape, and is considering it for our solution for patch management etc. but what i can see, it is not for F12 image deployment...